# Delete button wont work

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried for hours, and it still dont work. Please help me, my examen is in 5 hours and this is the last bit!
So i dont know whatS wrong

```
  /*Slett post i feed*/
     $Slettpost = $_POST['Slettpost'];
     If (isset($_POST['Slettpost'])) {
         { /* 1 = at det er noe som kan slettes */
             $Id = $_POST['Id'];
             $sql = "DELETE * FROM Bilder WHERE IdBilde='$Id'"; /* Id er alle tingene vi hr sagt denne variabelen skal gjøre - i dette
 tilfellet være en stor kobling, så når iden fjernes fjernes det som
 ligger i id variabelen, så i dette tilfellet enten posten eller
 videoen. */
             $kobling->query($sql); /*Lager koblingen mellom alt vi henter ut som er query */
           header('Location:Art%20Samling.php');
        }
     }

>               <form method='post'> 
>                     <input type='hidden' name='Slettpost' value = '1'>
>                     <input type='hidden' name='Id' value='".$r['IdBruker']."'>
>                     <input type='submit' value='Slett post'>
>                                         </form>
```

Thank you soo much!

Comment: probably something error by `$r['IdBruker']` that is null what is this?

Comment: *"it still dont work"* - We can't see your screen from here.  How exactly is this failing?  Also note that your code is wide open to SQL injection, which is often an invitation for bugs and unexpected behavior.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com - Learn about SQL injection and how to use prepared statements to prevent them. Your code is not safe at all and your database could be deleted in a few seconds without any need of deeper knowledge of your system.

Comment: There is no * in `DELETE * FROM`

Comment: I dont know which language this is, so im just asking: Is 'WHERE IdBilde' right? Because you used 'Bilder' in FROM

Comment: It is in norwegian, And also i tried with * but nothing happened. This is my first year with programming so i dont even know how to do that guys /: But thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

Rewatch your code, you had this on your IF condition -> {{}}.
And next time try to provide full english version of your code, it will be more usefull than norvegian lol.

And as said in comment section, SQL command for delete row(s) in table is :**DELETE FROM 'table' WHERE 'condition'** 
For preparing request in SQL, you should process this way :

```
if(isset($_POST['Slettpost'])&&!empty($_POST['Slettpost']))
{
    $Slettpost = $_POST['Slettpost']; // why affect this ? You don't use it in your code in any way..
    $Id = $_POST['Id'];
    $VarName = $dbconnector->prepare("DELETE FROM Bilder WHERE IdBilde= :id");
    $VarName->bindParam(":id", $Id);
    $VarName->execute();
    // some pertinent code here.. idk.
}
else
{
    // do whatever you want to do
}
```

Also you can check PHP Manuel [here](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdo.prepare.php) about prepared statement in PHP.

I hope it will help you to fix your issue.

By the way, next time provide some more usefull information about your issue(s).

Best regard.